# How to fire action in the controller when I select a file from an input file control found in edit form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, photo-upload

I have a code in editform like this.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Bind", "Student", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
<img id="sp" src="/Student/RetrieveImage/model.StudentID" alt="Photo" height=100 width=200 />
<input type="file" name="ImageData" id="ImageData" onchange="DI();"/>
}
```

And this in Student Controller

```
HttpPostedFileBase file;
public ActionResult Bind()
{
    file = Request.Files["ImageData"];
    file = Request.Files["ImageData"];
    return RedirectToAction("StudentEdit");
}
```

The begin form is found in editform which is a partial form. What I need is to fire the Bind Action when file is selected from input file. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You are working with an form(html element) to upload the image(with HTTP POST verb), in your example you have two main options to proceed with the upload:

1'st option: Create a submit input inside the form

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Bind", "Student", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{

    <input type="file" name="ImageData" id="ImageData" onchange="DI();"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submitbutton" value="Upload" />
}
```

2'nd option: submit the form with javascript, in this example I used the event that you created at the file element:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Bind", "Student", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <input type="file" name="ImageData" id="ImageData"  onchange="this.form.submit();"/>
}
```